# Detecting TF300 with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I'm just starting to look into Android programming, and have run into problem with eclipse detecting my TF300T. I assume that it should simply be plugging the USB cable.

I can use the AVD to test my code, however I'd like to see how it functions on a real device, any help will be appreciated.

I also made sure that the Google USB device update was installed through the manager, also the PC does detect the tablet, just not in Eclipse.

Comment: In windows you usually need a driver from the device manufacture to be able to use it inside eclipse.

Comment: Download the correct drivers from the Asus website. Google USB Device is probably not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

On your device, enable USB debugging (in Settings -> Applications -> Development), and make sure your connection is set to "charge only" (in Settings -> USB connection type -> Default connection type).

The specifics above are for my HTC Evo and may be different on your TF300T, but bottom line is you need to enable USB debugging and make sure the USB connection type is not set as a disk drive.

Comment: Hi,Thanks everyone for the input. I did enable USB debugging on the device, tho I didn't check the "charge only" I'll try once I have the device once I get home.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working by downloading the driver using Asus sync. Thanks everyone!